# Select all rows per query except for one

Tags: mysql

I've got a condition of a duplicate value in some rows - I want all rows that have that duplicate value to be deleted except for one.

So far I've got this, which returns all of the rows that have a duplicate value:

```
SELECT  nid, vid, title, hash
FROM    node_revision nr
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    node_revision nr
        WHERE   nr.hash = nr.hash
        LIMIT 1, 1
        )
```

But I would like to get all except the one with the lowest vid. How would I go about doing that?

For instance, the data:

```
nid     vid          title                        hash
2065    2081    First news story    77c0f020c160c108ed0f38e572e0ea64
2065    2082    First news story    77c0f020c160c108ed0f38e572e0ea64
2065    2083    First news story    77c0f020c160c108ed0f38e572e0ea64
2065    2084    First news story    77c0f020c160c108ed0f38e572e0ea64
```

I want to select all except the one with the vid of 2081.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT nr.nid, nr.vid, nr.title, nr.hash
  FROM node_revision nr
 WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
    FROM node_revision nri
   WHERE nri.vid < nr.vid
     AND nri.hash = nr.hash     
      )
```

Or in plain English: *'Give me all the rows for which there is another row that has a lower vid and the same hash'*

Comment: I want all the rows that have a higher vid than the lowest for the same hash.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander that is exactly what this does.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander I have updated the statement at the bottom to clarify

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE FROM node_revision a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
                FROM  node_revision b
                WHERE b.hash = a.hash
                AND b.vid <> (SELECT min(c.vid) 
                                FROM node_revsion c
                                WHERE c.nid = b.nid))`

Comment: Changing this to a delete query doesn't seem to work - delete FROM    node_revision nr
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    node_revision nr
        WHERE   nr.hash = nr.hash
        LIMIT 1, 1
        )

Comment: see the edit to add the AND inside of the inner select

Comment: This also doesn't seem to do what I want - it is showing a node with the lowest vid in a given set of duplicates. I'll post the data.

Comment: check that you are referencing the proper tables in the nested selects i.e. a, b, c

Comment: The second subquery selects the minimum vid from the whole table not the minimum for each set of dupes.